# Not able to read any values from Spring Boot's application.properties file in a Jersey based web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a Jersey based web application in Spring Boot and now I want to add properties file to my application. I added `applicationContext.xml` and `application.properties` in my classpath inside `src/main/resources` folder but when I try to access any property using `@Value` or using `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`, I am getting `NullPointerException`. Here is my code -

**web.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/Javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="TEST" version="3.0">
    <display-name>TestProject</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <icon>
        <large-icon>images/B.svg</large-icon>
    </icon>
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/Test</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
    
</beans>
```

**application.properties -**

```
demo.property=Demo
test.property=PropertyWorking
```

**Application.java -**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    
}
```

**JerseyResourceConfig.java -**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import com.demo.server.JPAEntityManagerFactory;

@ApplicationPath("api")
public class JerseyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyResourceConfig() {
        packages(this.getClass().getPackageName());
        
        Map<String, Object> loggingProperties=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        loggingProperties.put(LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_VERBOSITY_SERVER, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY);
        // loggingProperties.put(LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE_SERVER, );
        
        addProperties(loggingProperties);
        
        register(new AbstractBinder() {

            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindFactory(JPAEntityManagerFactory.class).to(EntityManager.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
            }});
    }
}
```

**The class file from where I am trying to access properties -**

```
@Provider
@Path("v1")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Restv1 {
    
    @Autowired
    private org.springframework.core.env.Environment env;

    @Value("${demo.property}")
    String testA;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("demoApi")
    public Response demoApi() {
        String testB = env.getProperty("test.property");
        logger.info("TEST PROPERTY FILE. VALUE FOR KEY demo.property IS - ", testA);
        System.out.println("TEST PROPERTY FILE. VALUE FOR KEY demo.property IS - "+ testA);
        logger.info("TEST PROPERTY FILE. VALUE FOR KEY test.property IS - ", testB);
        System.out.println("TEST PROPERTY FILE. VALUE FOR KEY test.property IS - "+ testB);
        ..
        //more code
        ..
      }
 }
```

When I build the war and deploy in tomcat and when I try to access this `/demoApi` API, I get following `NullPointerException` -

```
09-Jul-2021 15:59:49.016 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [com.server.rest.JerseyResourceConfig] in context with path [/..] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.server.rest.Restv1.demoApi(Restv1.java:83)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:475)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:397)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at com.server.HttpAuthFilter.doFilter(HttpAuthFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Please help. Where am I doing wrong? Am I missing any configurations?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "at com.server.rest.Restv1.demoApi(Restv1.java:83)" it's probably trying to parse a value that does not exist, what it's written on the 83rd row of that class ?

Comment: Sorry. Actually Line 83(in my workspace) in Restv1.java is - String testB = env.getProperty("test.property");

Comment: Most likely "env" doesn't have that property, that's why you're getting the null pointer exception

Comment: But how to check it? My property file do have "test.property" key in it, which this "env" is trying to fetch.

Comment: You set test.property = Property Working which is not seen as a environment variable, you have to write test.property = ${Property Working}

Comment: I tried this too but getting same error. I also tried to add system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" like this in applicationContext.xml --  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"
      system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>   But this also gave me same error.

Comment: Maybe you autowired environment wrong, do it without the full path, just write @Autowired Environment env; and a pop-up should appear to auto-import it (be sure to import the correct environment)

Comment: Did that too. Same error.

Comment: That propertysource annotation looks suspect, it should be on a class which is a configuration class. Such as your main application class, or any other class which is annotated with `@Configuration`. I wouldn't know why that would cause the Environment to not be successfully injected though, there may be multiple problems here.